# operation of elements in a set in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

In my recent work，it is about algebraic semantics.I want to expression an new operation of elements in a set in Isabelle, and the elements is very complex. 
This operation is an extension of the binary operation. and this binary operation have finished by locale easily. such as :a⊕b=c

```
locale Probjia = Prob + Prep + fixes probjiao :: "'b ⇒ 'b ⇒ 'b" (infixl "⊕" 90)
```

BUT,i do not know how to expression this operation of elements in a set. Tips: i do not know how many elements in this set.

I hope, ⊕A, A={a,b,c,d,......}, then ⊕A = a⊕b⊕c⊕d......

Can anyone give me some advises ? or some example i can learn by myself. My English is not very good, hope to express clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A commutative monoid operation can be lifted to **finite** sets using the operator `F` in the locale `comm_monoid_set`. You need a monoid such that the empty set can be represented as the neutral element. I recommend that you have a look how the pre-defined functions `sum` and `prod` are defined (enter `term "sum"` and and Ctrl-Click on `sum` to get to the definition). In your case, you probably want to declare a sublocale relationship:

```
context Probjia begin
sublocale probjiao: comm_monoid_set probjiao neutral_element_for_probjiao
  defines Probjiao = probjiao.F
```

where `neutral_element_for_probjiao` is the neutral element for your operation. After you've finished the proof, `Probjiao` then is the lifted version of your operator.

Comment: Sorry，to bother you agan. In term"sum": sublocale sum:comm_monid_set plus 0.

Comment: Sorry，to bother you again. In term"sum": sublocale sum:comm_monid_set plus 0. plus is a class. But，in my situation，probjiao is a locale, it's wrong. but,when probjiao is changed as class, it is OK. And,i don't want to change it.

Comment: My Isabelle snipped had a few typos which I've fixed, in particular I had written `comm_moniod_set` instead of `comm_monoid_set`.